# How to export/read an empty dataframe in R?

Tags: r, csv, shiny, read.csv

I am trying to export/import dataframes as csv files using `read.csv` and `write.csv` but I can't seem to manage the case when a `data.frame` is empty. Typically, if my `data.frame` is empty (i.e. it has column but no row names) `write.csv` creates an empty *.csv file and I get an error when I try to read it with `read.csv`. Any solution ?

EDITS:

The error message I get is:

I get the following error message:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = 
quote,  : 
les premières cinq lignes sont vides : abandon
```

Which translates into: the first 5 rows are empty : giving up.

My code lines are:

```
write.csv(DF.old,file="DF_old.csv",row.names=FALSE)
DF.old<-read.csv(file="DF_old.csv")
```

The type of the data in the dataframe is:

[image]

and it can get empty when I use the following commands:

```
DF.old <- DF.old[DF.old$exceptionnel==T]
DF.old<-DF.old  %>% 
      filter(!id_op %in% to_add$id_op)
```

Lastly this is in within a Shiny app.

Comment: Is it really an error or actually a warning? Please post the occurring message.

Comment: Why are you trying to write an empty data frame?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine with `data.table` at least.

```
> library(data.table)
> 
> #generate a data table with column name and no rows
> DT <- data.table(column1="value")[column1!="value"]
> 
> #print the data table
> DT
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: column1
> 
> #write the data table
> fwrite(DT, "test.csv")
> 
> #read the data table
> fread("test.csv")
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: column1
```

So, when written with `fwrite` and read back with `fread` there are no errors, and column names are preserved.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- data.frame(A=character(),B=numeric())
write.csv(dat, 'test.csv', row.names=FALSE)
dat2 <- read.csv('test.csv')
head(dat)
head(dat2)

# For Vincent
require(dplyr)
DF <- data.frame(a=c('A','B','C','A','A','B'),b=rnorm(6))  
DF.old <- DF %>% filter (a %in% 'D')
write.csv(DF.old,file="DF_old.csv",row.names=FALSE)
DF.old2<-read.csv(file="DF_old.csv")
```

I try this but get no errors and warnings. Please check your script and post your error message.

Comment: Could you post the script that generates DF.old? Or give more information such as the class type, the dimension and so on.

Comment: I have updated my code. I just cannot reproduce your problem. Have you tried `rm(list=ls())`, reboot the R session or something else? Have you tried to run the code posted by me and 'anotherfred' and find anything?

Comment: Both your codes work fine... Well maybe the difference is that mine is part of a Shiny app ?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with empty dataframe of 0 column and 0 row, `fwrite` from **data.table** fails. However, `write_csv` from **readr** succeeds in creating an empty csv file.

```
library(readr) # or library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame()
write_csv(df, "~/empty_df.csv")
# fwrite does not work
```